# Upgrading version of colorama for buildozer

Tags: android, python

I have a big problem. I am trying to use buildozer to package my application for android that I have written using kivy in Python 2. I have installed all dependencies, and I fell upon an error, stating:

```
ERROR: colorama version is 0.3.2, but python-for-android needs at least 0.3.3.
```

So I ran:

```
 pip install colorama --upgrade to upgrade it.
```

It finishes, but it also states that

```
Not uninstalling colorama at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

I thought it worked, but it turns out that the colorama at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is the one python sees first, and buildozer still doesn't work.

The problem is, for some reason, colorama seems to be at it's latest version when I type `aptitude upgrade colorama` , and pip needs colorama, so if I uninstall colorama, aptitude tells me I have to uninstall pip. pip just happens to be a dependancy of buildozer as well.

Update:
     I ran this all as root, previously stating su, exept for the buildozer commands.

Comment: Please go and ask Super User. Stack Overflow is for dealing with code, not software issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission error. Try running

```
sudo pip install colorama --upgrade
```